# ffmpeg could not find codec parameters for stream 0 on Ubuntu 22.04, works fine on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-22.04, nvidia-jetson-nano

I'm new to ffmpeg but I've got an odd issue which seems to arise from using it on different Ubuntu versions.

I have an NVIDIA Jetson Nano running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.9.201-tegra aarch64). Plugged into the Nano's carrier board is an embedded camera that shows up as a `Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. USB2.0 Camera RGB` when I run `lsusb`.

When I run this ffmpeg command, I can successfully record video from the camera, which seems to be `mjpeg` codec with `yuvj422p` pixel format. The output is as follows:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -an -vcodec libx264 test_capture.mp4
ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 166.142773, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 928x400, 100 fps, 100 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x558553df70] using cpu capabilities: ARMv8 NEON
[libx264 @ 0x558553df70] profile High 4:2:2, level 3.2, 4:2:2 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x558553df70] 264 - core 152 r2854 e9a5903 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'test_capture.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj422p(pc), 928x400, q=-1--1, 100 fps, 12800 tbn, 100 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=  192 fps= 65 q=-1.0 Lsize=     151kB time=00:00:01.89 bitrate= 654.4kbits/s dup=150 drop=0 speed=0.642x    
video:148kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.072495%
[libx264 @ 0x558553df70] frame I:1     Avg QP:23.62  size: 36953
[libx264 @ 0x558553df70] frame P:49    Avg QP:25.25  size:  2121
[libx264 @ 0x558553df70] frame B:142   Avg QP:30.55  size:    70
[libx264 @ 0x558553df70] consecutive B-frames:  1.0%  1.0%  0.0% 97.9%
[libx264 @ 0x558553df70] mb I  I16..4: 10.1% 78.8% 11.1%
[libx264 @ 0x558553df70] mb P  I16..4:  1.1%  1.9%  0.0%  P16..4: 19.1%  3.0%  2.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:72.8%
[libx264 @ 0x558553df70] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  2.7%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.1%  skip:97.2%  L0:36.8% L1:62.3% BI: 0.9%
[libx264 @ 0x558553df70] 8x8 transform intra:68.4% inter:77.4%
[libx264 @ 0x558553df70] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 42.0% 80.2% 41.3% inter: 2.2% 5.4% 0.2%
[libx264 @ 0x558553df70] i16 v,h,dc,p: 50% 17% 10% 23%
[libx264 @ 0x558553df70] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 21%  9% 32%  5%  7%  7%  5%  8%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x558553df70] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 24% 15% 12%  5% 14% 11%  8%  5%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x558553df70] i8c dc,h,v,p: 50% 12% 26% 12%
[libx264 @ 0x558553df70] Weighted P-Frames: Y:28.6% UV:28.6%
[libx264 @ 0x558553df70] ref P L0: 56.4% 28.2% 12.0%  2.5%  0.9%
[libx264 @ 0x558553df70] ref B L0: 93.4%  5.3%  1.3%
[libx264 @ 0x558553df70] ref B L1: 94.9%  5.1%
[libx264 @ 0x558553df70] kb/s:628.21
Exiting normally, received signal 2.
```

However, I'd like to replace this Nano with another that I've upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.9.299-tegra aarch64). The device still shows up as the same type when running `lsusb`. Running the exact same command results in the following:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -an -vcodec libx264 test_capture.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.22.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu --arch=arm64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x55cab86450] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: mjpeg, none(bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1856x800): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, none(bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1856x800, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Cannot determine format of input stream 0:0 after EOF
Error marking filters as finished
Exiting normally, received signal 2.
```

I'm not sure why I can't read this video stream when everything seems to be the same but the OS and the ffmpeg version.

I've checked the available codecs and pixel formats using `ffmpeg -codecs` and `ffmpeg -pix_fmts`:

Ubuntu 18.04.5, ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2:

`DEVIL. mjpeg                Motion JPEG (encoders: mjpeg mjpeg_vaapi )`

`IO... yuvj422p               3            16`

Ubuntu 22.04.1, ffmpeg version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1:

`DEVIL. mjpeg                Motion JPEG (decoders: mjpeg mjpeg_cuvid ) (encoders: mjpeg mjpeg_vaapi )`

`IO... yuvj422p               3            16`

So it seems like I should be able to record video on both with this codec/pixel format combination.

I've also tried forcing ffmpeg to use this combination on the 22.04 Nano with the following command:

`ffmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format mjpeg -framerate 100 -video_size 928x400 -pix_fmt yuvj422p -i /dev/video0 -an -vcodec libx264 test_capture.mp4`

But I get the same error. I've also tried increasing the `-analyzeduration` and `-probesize` arguments to 100M, with no luck.

Are there other commands or settings I should use? Should I downgrade my ffmpeg version if possible?